# Will invoking two synchronized methods in one line cause a deadlock?

Tags: java, synchronization

If a class has two synchronized methods:

```
public class A {
    public synchronized int do1() {...}
    public synchronized void do2(int i) {...}
}
```

Will invoking these two methods in one line cause a deadlock?

```
A a = new A();
a.do2(a.do1());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that in your example, **the two methods are not invoked concurrently**.

There is a clear strict order between them - `do2()` cannot be invoked until `do1()` is done!

Also note, the code is equivalent to

```
A a = new A();
int temp = a.do1();
a.do2(temp);
```

Comment: Was just about to mention this, +1